# How to create real objects with behavior (methods) in PowerShell?

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

Probably this question has been answered before.... but I have not found a specific answer to my needs.

BTW I'm using PowerShell 3

Well, I'm new in PowerShell but I have a lot of experience as a C# developer, so working with objects is very important to me.

So I'm wondering if there's a **clean way** to apply *OOP concepts* (well not all of them, though that would be awesome) in a PowerShell script, for example there are specific things that I would like to do.

**Note: I'm aware that I can write C# code in PowerShell to create DTO's and also that I can create PowerShell binary modules in C#, I have done that in the past, but what I'm looking for now is the ability to write all my code in PowerShell but in an *Object Oriented way*.**

Things I would like to do:

- Create an object in PowerShell, and expose a function written in PowerShell as well, something like this:

  ```
  function New-Person
  (
      [Parameter()][string]$firstName
  )
  {
      function Walk()
      {
          Write-Host "Walking...";
      }

      $person = New-Object psobject;

      $person | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name FirstName -Value $firstName;

      #This line does not work
      #$person | Add-Member -MemberType CodeMethod -Name Walk -Value Walk;

      return $person;
  }

  $MyPerson = New-Person -firstName "JP";

  $MyPerson;

  #This line does not work
  $MyPerson.Walk();
  ```
- Encapsulate behavior, which means create functions inside my object and then mark them as private
- *[Nice to have].* Create base classes so I can inherit and specialize my behavior overriding methods
- *[Nice to have].* Create interfaces so I can start thinking in unit testing in isolation my PowerShell methods (I know there are tools like Pester to do this I'm just focusing on OOP features)

What I have done so far is **creating objects with properties only (DTO's)** but I'd like to add behavior to my objects

I'd appreciate if you guys point me in the right direction

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Two options to create object with methods:

1. Add-Member
2. New-Module -AsCustomObject

Code samples:

```
$person | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptMethod -Value {
    'I do stuff!'
}

$person = New-Module -AsCustomObject -ScriptBlock {
    $Property = 'value'
    [string]$Other = 'Can be strongly typed'

    function MyMethod {
        'I do stuff!'
    }

}
```

EDIT: speaking of private/ public... In latter example property won't show up "by default". You can decide what is public using `Export-ModuleMember` and specify `-Variable` (properties) and/or `-Function` (methods) that will be public. Without explicit `Export-ModuleMember` it will behave same as in "normal" module - export only functions (methods).

Comment: Both examples work great. I'd like to use the first one. Is there any way to ask for parameters in the `ScriptMethod` - `Value` body? to be able to do something like `$MyPerson.Walk("number of mioles or whateva");`

Comment: Add a regular `param` block inside the function definition. e.g.  `$obj = "foo" | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptMethod -Value { param( $first, $second) "first is $first, second is $second" } -Name DoStuff -PassThru;  $obj.DoStuff('abc', '123')`

Comment: I'm assuming we'll start with `$person = New-Object -TypeName PSObject`, right? Otherwise, `Add-Member` gives a prompt to `Supply values for the following parameters: Name:`. The code from @latkin works as-is, as does this [solution from Poshcode.org](http://poshcode.org/3719).

Answer (score 7):

PowerShell v5 introduces full class support, making it easy to build your own classes with properties and implement methods.

Check out Trevor's great blog post about the topic here. [Trevor Sullivan, Implementing a .net Class](http://trevorsullivan.net/2014/10/25/implementing-a-net-class-in-powershell-v5/)

#### Standalone Example

Here is a PowerShell class of a made up type called a Fox, which has a `.Deploy()` method, should show how this is done

```
class Fox {
    # describes the sixe of the fox
    [String] $Size;
    # Property: the foxes color
    [String] $Color;

    # Constructor: Creates a new Fox object, with the specified
    #              size and name / owner.
    Fox([string] $NewSize, [String] $NewName) {
        # describes the sixe of the fox
        $this.Size = $NewSize;
        # Property: the foxes color
        $this.Color = $NewName;
    }

    # Method: Change the size of the fox     
    [void] Morph([UInt32] $Amount) {
        try {
            $this.Size = $this.Size - $Amount;
        }
        catch {
            Write-Warning -Message 'You tried to set an invalid size!';
        }
    }

    # Method: BreakGlass resets the beer size to 0.
    [void] Deploy() {
        Write-Warning -Message "The $($this.Color) fox, which is $($this.Size) in stature, goes off into the distance"        
    }
}
```

And in practice:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the link, that is exactly what I was not able to find myself.

Answer (score 4):

If you want **full** OOP (including inheritance, although not interfaces), then [PSClass](http://psclass.codeplex.com/) is an MS-PL licensed implementation.

Comment: Just for the record, I did not down voted your answer, I already found that project and I'm doing some prove of concepts. Voting this answer up

Comment: Nice... +1 and will have to play with it.