# Are the PowerShell modules the closer "thing" of classes in C#?

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

This is a continuation of my previous question:

[How to create real objects with behavior (methods) in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14835983/1268570)

I think that now I'm able to encapsulate my behavior in classes but I still think this approach is hacky, and I would like to address this problem *the PowerShell way*

So, Powershell modules appear to be the answer...

I would like to know if for example I want to encapsulate behavior in an Object Oriented way in PowerShell what would be the best option/approach?

Are PowerShell modules designed for this purpose?

**Edit 01**

In other words how do you guys write your scripts?

Do you just go writing them in a *procedural way*

or...

Is there a cleaner way to apply some Object Oriented Programming concepts when writing PowerShell scripts?

Comment: Modules don't really seem like they introduce an object system if one wasn't available in PSH before.

Comment: I just updated my question.

Comment: So... you're asking the same question again despite having gotten your answer? (Two of them in fact.)

Comment: If you read carefully, it's not the same. The last question gave me the technical tools to acomplish what I wanted, now I want to know what would be the best approach in PowerShell

Comment: Or, you could write this question more carefully, outlining your specific concerns with the solution you have, instead of just vaguely asking for "cleaner". Also, "the best approach" is likely to get closed as "not constructive" - there may be many approaches, valid for different use cases.

Comment: I appreciate that but I think it was concrete enough so that you answered it in the first place...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

dont know if it is the best method, but why not use pscustomobject?

```
$o=New-Object -TypeName pscustomobject -Property @{"val"="test"}
Add-Member -InputObject $o -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name upper -Value {$this.val.toUpper()}
$o.upper()

TEST
```

or maybe you'll find happyness with this project on codeplex : http://psclass.codeplex.com/

Comment: That project looks awesomeeee. Thank you man. I'm extremely strict when writing my C# code and now I'm working with PowerShell and I was just not happy to write **UGLY Procedural code**. I think I'm going to create some prove of concepts using PSClass. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

My take on this as follows. I do not believe that scripting languages have ever been object oriented. Most of them would support some kind of object models but this is not their main purpose.

Powershell does support it because it's built on top of .NET and hence you have full access to object model of .NET.

You can write in-line C# code in powershell script (with classes and all) and compile it on the fly and then execute repeatedly. Once you've get used to do this it's not difficult at all.

On it's own powershell does not provide an object system far beyond what you can found in .NET.

If you have not found it already please refer to [Add-Member](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849879.aspx) cmdlet, that would be the closest to what you are after, if for any religious or cultural reasons you don't want to embed c# classes in your powershell code.

Hope this helps.